# Unable to pass separate Uri of two images through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, uri, android-camera-intent

Im not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried a lot to fix this code but to no avail. Basically the user clicks two images on Activity A. Images are called medicine_bill and other_bill. `Uri.getPath()` is passed for each image via intent to activity B. But in activity B, im getting the same Uri for both the images and hence unable to load them both. Scale image is a function to reduce the dimensions of the image.

```
    btnAddMedicineBill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File f=getOutputMediaFile("Medit_medicine");
            medicineBillUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, medicineBillUri);
            startActivityForResult(i, BILL_IMAGE_MEDICINE);
        }
    });

    btnAddOtherBill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            File f=getOutputMediaFile("Medit_Other");
            otherBillUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, otherBillUri);
            startActivityForResult(i, BILL_IMAGE_OTHER);
        }
    });
```

The path generator to which the image is saved

```
private File getOutputMediaFile(String name) {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "medit_app");
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                name+timeStamp + ".jpg");
        Log.d("reached a", mediaFile.toString());
        return mediaFile;
    }
```

The onActivityResult() code is as follows -

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(String.valueOf(requestCode), String.valueOf(resultCode));

        if (requestCode==BILL_IMAGE_MEDICINE){
            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
                Bitmap bitmap = ScaleImage(medicineBillUri.getPath());
                ivMedicineBillImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                _medicineImageTaken =true;
                }
        }
        if (requestCode==BILL_IMAGE_OTHER){
            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
                Bitmap bitmap1 = ScaleImage(otherBillUri.getPath());
                ivOtherBillImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
                _otherImageTaken =true;
            }
        }
    }
```

The startActivity() for Activity B

```
Intent intentToStamp = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
intentToStamp.putExtra(BILL_OTHER_IMAGE_URL, otherBillUri.getPath());
intentToStamp.putExtra(BILL_MEDICINE_IMAGE_URL, medicineBillUri.getPath());
Log.d("Other Bill",otherBillUri.getPath() );
Log.d("Medicine Bill",medicineBillUri.getPath() );
```

The Log values at this point

```
Other Bill﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/medit_app/Medit_Other20151123_152716.jpg
Medicine Bill﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/medit_app/Medit_medicine20151123_152707.jpg
```

And finally the getExtras() code in Activity B

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
medicineBillImageUrl =intent.getStringExtra(BILL_MEDICINE_IMAGE_URL);
Log.d("Medicine", medicineBillImageUrl)
otherBillImageUri =intent.getStringExtra(BILL_OTHER_IMAGE_URL);
Log.d("Other", otherBillImageUri);
```

At this point both Logs are appearing as

```
Medicine Bill﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/medit_app/Medit_medicine20151123_152707.jpg
Other Bill﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/medit_app/Medit_medicine20151123_152707.jpg
```

Also the actual image is being stored as /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20151123_152707.jpg

Comment: check that, BILL_MEDICINE_IMAGE_URL and BILL_OTHER_IMAGE_URL strings have different values

Comment: I prefer if you use strings to handle these paths, on intent you can easily pass and on the other activity do the conversion is better.

Comment: I didnt understand. I am using strings as the identifier for the intents which I have defined in a Constants.class (public static String A_B_C ="a_b_c" ) to avoid spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define to different key for the

```
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OTHER_BILL, otherBillUri);
```

and

```
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDICINE_BILL, medicineBillUri);
```